# NUnit v3 alpha: trying to get parallel tests to work

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit

I'm trying to get parallel tests to work in NUnit v3, however, the tests don't seem to.

Considering the following test class:

```
namespace NUnitAlpha3Experimental
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
    class DummyTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void MustSuccess()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
            FileIO.appendToFile("output.txt", Reflexion.GetCurrentMethodName());
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustFail()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            FileIO.appendToFile("output.txt", Reflexion.GetCurrentMethodName());
            Assert.IsFalse(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my tests, "MustFail" is always outputted before "MustSuccess". "MustSuccess" should be outputted first if the tests were ran in parallel. Maybe there's something wrong with my attributes. I don't know.

Please help. Thank you.

edit: I added the /workers=8 to my command line:
[...] \NUnit3\nunit-console NUnitAlpha3Experimental.exe /framework:net-4.5 -workers=8
but still, my tests dont seem to run in parallel.

More info here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/_Zcd3EjiJGo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the author of NUnit, parallel test cases are not yet implemented. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/_Zcd3EjiJGo
Parallel testing of fixtures is implemented thought.